# Generating messages for rosjava?

Tags: ros, client-rosjava, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Platform: Diamondback, Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

I'm using rosjava, so I need to generate class files for all messages.

I tried using the rosjava_deps package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava_deps), but it depends on the genmsg_cpp package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/genmsg_cpp), which appears to be gone.

How do I auto-generate the message source or class files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9565/generating-messages-for-rosjava?/) by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2011-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind, I just realised that all I have to do is remove dependencies on all packages that are no longer present in Diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) with karma: 32 on 2011-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-17**:
Hi, I am trying to publish a message from rospy to a subscriber in rosjava. I am using ros hydro. I copy pasted the subscriber code from the tutorials into my rosjava folder and built it with catkin_make. I am getting errors related to adding the dependencies. I need to add them in the gradle file i think and i dont know how. can you help me with this? thanks

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-11-21**:
Perhaps you should open up a new question for this azair. Keyword it with java and I'll respond.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-26**:
Hello Daniel..I posted my question here
http://answers.ros.org/question/104186/trying-to-publish-from-rospy-and-subscribe-with-rosjava/